# Migrating RabbitMQ spring-cloud-stream from springboot 2 to springboot 3

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I am updating a project that sends rabbitMQ messages from spring boot to to spring boot 3
I THINK the current springboot 2 project uses spring-cloud-stream v3.2.3 to send the messages
Here is a snippet of the service class where it sends the rabbitMQ messages

`@EnableBinding(MessageChannels.class)
public class MessageService {

```
@Autowired
private MessageChannels messageSource;

public void send(String id, Map<String, Object> data, MessageChannel messageChannel, MessageType messageType, String messageTypeHeader) {

    try {
        MessageDTO message = new MessageDTO();
        message.setId(id);
        message.setData(data);
        message.setMessageType(messageType);

        Message m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message)
                .setHeader("messageType", messageTypeHeader)
                .setHeader("messageSourceType", MessageSourceType.PLATFORM.name())
                .build();

        messageChannel.send(m);
    }
}
```

`

The last statement, the send method is from an abstract class that is part of springboot 2 spring-cloud-stream (I think?) that implements the MessageChannel interface  from spring-messaging v5.3.29.  The code below is from that library

```
package org.springframework.messaging;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface MessageChannel {
    long INDEFINITE_TIMEOUT = -1L;

    default boolean send(Message<?> message) {
        return this.send(message, -1L);
    }

    boolean send(Message<?> message, long timeout);
}
```

So with spring boot 3, I get an execution error that required bean for MessageChannel (interface) cannot be found.  Apparently the abstract classes that implemented that interface are no longer included in springboot 3.

My question is does the prescribed upgrade path call for us to throw out this huge amount of code like above which utilizes MessageChannel interface and (to instead use the StreamBridge method), or can we keep the code and continue sending messages using the MessageChannel interface in Springboot 3 (which I THINK uses spring-cloud-stream 4.04)?

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with Spring Boot. You are describing changes to spring-cloud-stream that have been deprecated for over 4 years now and finally removed from the code base. Basically we moved from annotation-based programming model to functional. So yes StreamBridge is one of the way of sending messages. The other one is Function and Supplier, but without knowing your requirements i can't say which one is best suited for you.

Comment: What is the easiest way to get the above code working with latest SCS? I just need to know what code changes need to be made for it to run, since the dependencies were removed

Comment: I don't know your requirement. You assume it could be extracted from your code sample. .  it's not. We have plenty of example of `StreamBridge` and 'Supplier' in the reference manual. We also have tons of running test cases, you can look there as well.

Comment: The requirement is to send to rabbitMQ the message passed to the send() method in the first code sample. It should use the messageChannel passed to the method also.  I looked for specific examples on how to port this to functional but couldn't find any and just need assistance

Comment: MessageChannel is an internal abstraction and represents a binding. Users receive and send messages from/to bindings. StreamBridge has a single `send` method to send message to the bindings. This section explains all the details - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources